# Mercurial automatic buld workflow?

Tags: mercurial

I'm trying to replicate a workflow using Mercurial. It seems like this should be common, but I'm not quite sure how to do the magic bits.

1. User A creates changesets A1 and A2. User A does not have changesets B or C.
2. A1 and A2 are submitted to the server, which puts them in a queue.  Changesets from other users B and C are ahead in the queue.
3. Each changeset (B then C then A1/A2) is rebased into the main branch automatically, built, and then accepted into the trunk (or rejected).
4. The codebase is very large so builds take a long time. In the meantime A3 and A4 are generated by User A.
5. User A does a pull and gets B', C', and the new A1'/A2' without getting duplicates. A3 and A4 move to the tip of the trunk as development continues.

Step 5 is the one that has me the most stymied. A "git pull --rebase" seems to recognize that the changesets are the same and so A1/A2 disappear whereas with Hg it is a conflict. I don't expect Hg to be exactly the same workflow, I just need some way for a developer to be able to pull the trunk and not have to do manual fix-up of their tree to get their changesets in order. I also need some explainable workflow as to how to recover if your changeset is rejected. Does anyone have experience with this type of workflow that can recommend a tactic?

Thanks

Edit: Here's a simulator for the workflow. I'm certainly willing to try any other workflow that will solve the problem of being able to continue to build while changesets are progressing through acceptance and coming back smoothly.

```
rm -rf master
rm -rf build
rm -rf c1
rm -rf c2
rm -rf c3
rm -rf bundles

# Master repository
mkdir master
hg init master
echo x >> master/m1.txt
hg -R master add master/m1.txt
hg -R master commit master/m1.txt -m"m-1"
echo x >> master/m1.txt
hg -R master commit master/m1.txt -m"m-2"
echo x >> master/m1.txt
hg -R master commit master/m1.txt -m"m-3"

# Build repository
hg clone master build

# Setup first client
hg clone master c1
echo x >> c1/client1.txt
hg -R c1 add c1/client1.txt
hg -R c1 commit c1/client1.txt -m"c1-1"
echo x >> c1/client1.txt
hg -R c1 commit c1/client1.txt -m"c1-2"

# Setup second client
hg clone master c2
echo x >> c2/client2.txt
hg -R c2 add c2/client2.txt
hg -R c2 commit c2/client2.txt -m"c2-1"
echo x >> c2/client2.txt
hg -R c2 commit c2/client2.txt -m"c2-2"

# Setup third client
hg clone master c3
echo x >> c3/client3.txt
hg -R c3 add c3/client3.txt
hg -R c3 commit c3/client3.txt -m"c3-1"
echo x >> c3/client3.txt
hg -R c3 commit c3/client3.txt -m"c3-2"

# Create the 3 bundles simulating the queue; all clients have pushed
# Hopefully this is done with a push hook
# All changesets are still draft phase
mkdir bundles
hg -R c2 bundle bundles/c2.bundle
hg -R c3 bundle bundles/c3.bundle
hg -R c1 bundle bundles/c1.bundle

# Process first bundle
hg -R build pull bundles/c2.bundle --rebase
hg -R build update
hg -R build push master

# Client 1 pulls at this point
hg -R c1 pull master -u --rebase

# Process second and third bundle
hg -R build pull bundles/c3.bundle 
hg -R build rebase -b 5 -d 4
hg -R build pull bundles/c1.bundle
hg -R build rebase -b 7 -d 6
hg -R build push master

# Client 1 pulls again, getting the changesets that were pushed
hg -R c1 pull master -u --rebase
```

Answer (score 1):

There's one difference between git and mercurial usually-used setups: git often allows rebasing, pruning and other rewrite / destructive operations on other people or remote repositories - mercurial by default does not and only allows amend operations.

However, there's a mercurial way: mercurial introduced some time ago the concept of [phases](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Phases), notably the unmutable phase *public* and the mutable phase *draft*. You can now declare repositories as *[non-publishing](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Phases#Publishing_Repository)* (it's a but unfortunate term in my eyes - it basically means that commits pushed there do NOT become phase public but remain in draft phase, thus mutable.

Thus setup your "central" repository as one of those non-publishing repositories, tell all your contributors to make use of a reasonably modern mercurial **and to push changes as phase draft** (or make sure so in a server-side hook and reject pushes of new changesets with public phase - but that might be problematic). Mercurials exchange of obsolescence markers makes sure that users get the information of which changesets become deprecated and by which new changesets they are being replaced.

The server-side setup then will need to take care of changing the phase of the accepted changesets from *draft* to *public*.

Mind: once a changeset is converted to phase public, that changeset becomes unmutable. And the phase will propagate to all who pull - and thus even reverting the phase to draft, and changing or pruning that changeset WILL inevitably permanently leave the repos of all who pulled with extra changesets which everyone will have to prune manually themselves!

You (and all your contributors) also probably should have a look at the [evolve extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/EvolveExtension) which makes handling non-publishing repositories and working with and exchanging mutable changesets and their modifications much more comfortable.

Comment: Thanks. I reread the docs and tried it. Draft phase would make things easier on the server trying to do a rebase, but that isn't the part that I'm having problems with. I want to be able to send changes to the server, have them applied or rejected, and pull them back the repository inclusive of changes from all developers in an automated way. I can't figure out how to disseminate the changesets to developers once they are applied without leaving debris in their repository. Even draft phase changesets don't rebase away so the developer still has multiple duplicate changesets.

Comment: That perception is somewhat wrong (and somewhat right). That's what the evolve extension does for you: creating the appropriate obsolescence markers for the rebase operations. And those markers *are* pulled, thus no-one will be left with "debris".

Comment: Thanks; I see how the markers work. The process works as long as there aren't any intervening pulls. A pushes but B, C, D are in the queue. A is working and then pulls, getting B and C. Once that happens, regardless of whether it's a rebase or merge, things go poorly albeit it in different ways. With rebase the obsolescence markers don't remove and it's a conflict; with a merge revision you must evolve which puts it on the tip.

Comment: You probably do not want to call jenkins to build 'tip', but always tell jenkins to build a certain revision (which then can be queued to be built).
E.g. my build hook (changegroup) looks like this, calling jenkings by changeset ID: https://kallithea.openttdcoop.org/misc/files/f307114ea42083bfe1904ab1945889454fef7ce3/mercurial/hooks/invoke_jenkins.sh

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I can't see how it helps to build a different stamp. My problem is on the client. The team is large and active and builds will queue. There seems to be no way to continue working with a repo that combines my pushed changes with fixes others have pushed while waiting for acceptance and then getting the accepted changes smoothly.